# 2nd static ip address does not connect to the server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

Apache server starts with no errors. I have ip 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 set up as static IP's. 'https://www.site1.com' connects with the server. 'https://www.site2.com' does not connect to the server.

virtual host file contents for site1.com:

```
Listen 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 1.1.1.1:443

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    RewriteEngine On
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    ServerName site1.com
    ...
    SSLEngine On
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

virtual host file contents for site2.com:

```
Listen 2.2.2.2:81
Listen 2.2.2.2:444

<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:81>
    ServerName site2.com
    RewriteEngine On
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:444>
    ServerName site2.com
    ...
    SSLEngine On
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

results of 'netstat -lpn':

```
tcp        0      0 2.2.2.2:81       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 2.2.2.2:444      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

There is nothing else on ports 81 or 444. The results of 'grep -r Listen /etc/apache2' (excluding repeat in sites-enabled dir):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com:Listen 1.1.1.1:80
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com:Listen 1.1.1.1:443
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com:Listen 2.2.2.2:81
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com:Listen 2.2.2.2:444
```

site2 DNS Records:

```
A/AAAA Records
Hostname    IP Address       TTL            Options
            2.2.2.2          Default    Edit | Remove
mail        2.2.2.2          Default    Edit | Remove
www         2.2.2.2          Default    Edit | Remove
```

ping 2.2.2.2 results:

```
64 bytes from 2.2.2.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=32.897 ms
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to http://www.site2.com/, you're going to port 80. Since that site is listening on port 81, and the listener on port 80 doesn't know about it, it doesn't work. You either have to make both sites listen on port 80 or you have to go to http://www.site2.com:81/

Comment: https://www.site2.com:81 doesn't connect either.

Comment: Are you trying HTTP or HTTPS? If the latter, you have to specify port 444, since that's what you configured it for.

Comment: oh brother. right. 444 works. now... what to do. specifying a port for the general public isn't going to work. need two ips for two different ssl certs. i thought i had to bind the ips to different ports. maybe NIC.

Comment: You can specify `Listen *:80` and `Listen *:443`. You an have both IPs listening on the standard ports - that's usually how it's done. The `Listen` directive is put in a common file, not in the site-specific or IP-specific files.

Comment: will give that a try. didn't work last time i tried it but don't remember why.

Comment: Listen *:80 and *:443 didn't work. 2nd site kept using the first site SSL vert. when i went back to an empty ports.conf and put all listening and virtual host references to ip and port (e.g. 2.2.2.2:80) everything worked. :=] doin' cartwheels here.